# In Asp.Net core Odata, how to prevent filter string from replacing text passed

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, odata, asp.net-core-5.0

I am passing an `odata` query as below

```
http://localhost:5000/odata/Levels?$filter=contains(Code, '+14')
```

However when this lands in my controller I see that the filter object received is being replaced as

```
{contains(Code, ' 14')}
```

As you can see `+14` is being replaced  `14` where + is replaced with a space due to which my query is failing. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You need to encode the value, to pass it to the odata controller as you want it.

Comment: @MihailStancescu: can you please help me how I will be able to encode this? I am using Angular fronted here.

Comment: @Kiran this has nothing to do with Angular or OData. In a URL, certain characters have special meaning and need to be encoded (like `/`, `:', `#`,'?'`). In a URL the plus sign is a whitespace. That's why you see `' 14'`

Comment: BTW any OData client library would take care of encoding.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I see... this is really helpful. let me try to fix this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
http://localhost:5000/odata/Levels?$filter=contains(Code, encodeURIComponent('+14'))
```

I don't know how you generate the rest of the URI but you should replace `+14` with an encoded representation before sending it the the server.

Comment: OData is unable to recognize that `encodeURIComponent()` i see this message `"An unknown function with name 'encodeURIComponent' was found. This may also be a function import or a key lookup on a navigation property, which is not allowed."`

Comment: Also I think the URI is getting encoded by default as i can see %20 and %27 etc being added to the path that is ending up on the controller.

Comment: `encodeURIComponent` is a JavaScript function. It has no effect when it appears in a URL. Even if OData recognized this function, it would be applied on the *server*, on the decoded URL. The plus sign would still be translated to a whitespace

Comment: Thanks! I am selecting this as a answer as the idea was correct. function showed as an example indicated that I needed to encode the search text as Zhi Lv and  Panagiotis Kanavos also mentioned before generating the Odata url.

Answer (score 1):

> As you can see +14 is being replaced  14 where + is replaced with a
> space due to which my query is failing. How can I fix this issue?

Replace the `+` with `%2B`, then the odata query like this:

```
http://localhost:5000/odata/Levels?$filter=contains(Code, '%2B14')
```